# File Upload in Jmeter for POST method, when we have binary based form data

Tags: api, file-upload, jmeter, http-post, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to perform a file upload operation using jmeter for an API POST method. In Jmeter it requests results in 403 but in webpage it is 200.

Referred as many online resources and given multiple attempts i am not able to crack the solution.

How to handle the below form data in jmeter 4.0, As you could notice, there are 2 things, files and filedetails. How to handle this ?

I have also included the header value. Please look into it.

Below is the form data of POST METHOD:

------WebKitFormBoundarylyJiQdD1alYKbAKW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Sample_Report.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarylyJiQdD1alYKbAKW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedetails"

{"serviceRequestId":"RandomNumber","filedetails":[{"fileName":"Sample_Report.pdf","fileUniqueName":"Randomnumber-a575d680-ceb0-11e9-a25d-2590f89b0ed0.pdf","fileType":"application/pdf","fileSize":1117730,"status":"New"}]}
------WebKitFormBoundarylyJiQdD1alYKbAKW--

Request Headers:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarylyJiQdD1alYKbAKW

I should be able to upload a single / multiple file through the JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload a file using JMeter, try following approach:

1. Use HTTP Request Sampler and add all the necessary details like Server, Port, Path, Method etc.
2. In `File Upload section` of HTTP Sampler include following

   ```
   File Path = Sample_Report.pdf
   Parameter Name = files
   MIME Type = multipart/form-data [if this does not work use application/pdf]
   ```
3. In `Parameters section` of HTTP Sampler include following

   ```
   Name = filedetails
   Value = {"serviceRequestId":"RandomNumber","filedetails":[{"fileName":"Sample_Report.pdf","fileUniqueName":"Randomnumber-a575d680-ceb0-11e9-a25d-2590f89b0ed0.pdf","fileType":"application/pdf","fileSize":1117730,"status":"New"}]}
   ```
4. Make sure to check `Use multipart/form-data`
5. Add header whichever is required in Header Manager [initially dont include this, if it does not work with above settings, then only include Header Manager]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of configuring JMeter to simulate file upload is just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Configure JMeter for Recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose "File -> Templates - Recording" and click "Create"
   - Expand HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
2. Copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Perform the upload in the browser
4. JMeter will generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

For more complex scenarios you might require building your request manually, refer [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/) article for more details if needed.